# Assimp skeletal animation gpu skinning and blending

Tags: skinning, gpu

Does anyone know any open source projects that would allow me to load a file with assimp and make a simple API like LoadModel(), PlayAnimation(int keyframe_start, int keyframe_end), BlendAnimation(int seconds, int id), for example? It requires GPU skinning with matrix pallete or dual quaternions. I found something here:
http://files.zylinski.se/skeletal_animation/ But I am not sure if that supports blending of multiple animations. Can someone please have a look at that link and tell me if it does? if it does not then would it be hard to add blending to it? Sorry I am really new to 3D programming, only been learning 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code:

- [OGLDev 38: Assimp Animation](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html),
- Abdallah Dib's [iOS GLES tutorials](http://www.virtual-vision.net/4.html).

OGRE also support [skeletal animation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_76.html).

Answer (score 1):

[SmartBody](http://smartbody.ict.usc.edu/) is a character animation platform, I think it supports both transitioning (fading from one motion to the other) and blending ( combining multiple animations).

Don't know if the skinning is done on the GPU though.